# Los votos de amigos traen baja calidad a SOes

Tags: discusión, respuesta, votos-positivos

¡Hola!

Soy un **nuevo contribuidor de SOes** (a una semaña) y ya me di cuenta de que: ***los votos de amigos traen baja calidad a SOes***

#### Ejemplos

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246515/concatenar-cadenas-sin-el-0-en-c/), la que tiene más puntos, no solo no compila como hace un **grave acceso a memoria no válida** (*segmentation fault*).

En [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247489/memoria-din%C3%A1mica-uso-de-realloc), la que tiene más puntos **no és la respuesta** y la segunda **no compila** (y igual tenia un grave error de *fuga de memoria*).

#### Mis preguntas

- ¿El **SOes es consciente de lo qué si pasa**?
- ¿Si lo está, **qué medidas toma para mejorar y mantener la calidad de las respuestas**?

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices de "votos de amigos"

Comment: Votos de personas que quieren promover a los amigos.

Comment: Tienes pruebas de que los votos a esas personas están influenciados por amistad?

Comment: @pikoh No, igual lo puede ser por desconocer el asunto, pero con intento de promover *unos*.

Comment: Ahí voy @sbrubes . Los votos son anonimos y no puedes saber de donde proceden. Muchos pueden ser por el "criterio de autoridad" al ser eferion un usuario con mucha rep. En cuanto a tus preguntas, SOes  permite que todo el mundo vote tenga conocimiento o no, amigos o no. Tu haces bien en dejar comentarios en las publicaciones y en votar como creas adecuado. Si la publicacion es mala o no funciona, tarde o temprano más comentarios y votos lo corroborarán. Un saludo

Comment: '¿El SOes es consciente de lo qué si pasa?' ¿Qué quieres decir aquí?

Comment: @asier_2 De que la calidad está bajando.

Comment: El sistema de votaciones es el mismo en toda la red StackExchange. Cada usuario es libre de votar positiva o negativamente la publicación que quiera, por razones objetivas o subjetivas. En el caso que expones, C++ no está en mi ámbito de conocimiento, pero los dos usuarios que apuntas son los mas reputados en esa etiqueta. Por mi parte, dudo de que haya un favoritismo hacia ellos, mas allá de que un usuario de alta reputación suele ser favorecido en votos. De todas maneras, veo prematura tu opinión con solo una semana el sitio, pero eso es sólo mi opinión personal :)

Comment: @pikoh Por cierto que sí, es prematura. ;) Pero el mismo no me pasa en otros sitios del SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ¿El SOes es consciente de lo qué si pasa?

Que alguna gente vota a veces de forma más positiva a la gente que conoce y con la que tiene amistad es algo conocido. No es ideal, pero es normal. Lo que sería más preocupante es si dicha votación ocurre de forma continuada y sistemática.

Por eso en SOes (y en toda la red de Stack Exchange) existen programas que monitorizan las votaciones sospechosas (ya sean positivas o negativas), comprobando que los usuarios no puedan votarse a sí mismos (utilizando cuentas fantasma) o a sus "amigos" (o "enemigos") de forma serial. Los sistemas automáticos quitan los votos "amigos", pudiendo incluso tomar otras acciones y notificando a los moderadores de la situación.

Además, los moderadores cuentan con herramientas que permiten ver estadísticas de votos y comprobar si existen patrones sospechosos, para evitar el tipo de situaciones que comentas.

> ¿Si lo está, qué medidas toma para mejorar y mantener la calidad de las respuestas?

Aparte de los sistemas explicados arriba, la comunidad es eso: una comunidad. Se crea y se construye a base de la participación de los usuarios y de sus acciones.

Como dicen: "*Puedes engañar a todo el mundo algún tiempo. Puedes engañar a algunos todo el tiempo. Pero no puedes engañar a todo el mundo todo el tiempo.*" Si una publicación es mala o de baja calidad, no importa cuántos amigos tenga el usuario, la comunidad con sus votos va a acabar haciendo que las respuestas buenas suban y las respuestas malas bajen.

Answer (score 7):

En el primer caso que expones, aunque admitiéramos que @eferion en su última edición te "copió", la verdad es que su respuesta es mucho más clara e instructiva que la tuya, en la que realidad no explicas nada más allá de un escueto

> Tu problema no es en el terminador de strings, pero los terminadores de lineas.

De hecho, tu respuesta tiene +2, una buena puntuación (te puedo asegurar que en [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) esa ya es una puntuación para estar contento), pero lo mas importante es **que el op aceptó la respuesta de @eferion**.

Del segundo caso no puedo opinar sobre que *la que tiene más puntos no es la respuesta*, ya que no controlo la tecnología para afirmarlo o desmentirlo, pero esto:

> y la segunda no compila

lo dudo, ya que @paperbirmaster proporciona un [enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0poU5KEZapRxd1qP) donde se ve que compila y funciona.

En resumen: he estado analizando un poco tu trayectoria esta semana y en mi opinión personal se intuye que mas que la calidad del sitio, parece preocuparte tu propia reputación.

Si me admites un consejo, creo que al menos en S.O. en español, hay varios comportamientos que no están muy bien vistos, como por ejemplo solicitar puntos a otros usuarios, o tratar de desacreditar la respuesta de otros para provocar que un OP acepte tu respuesta.

Esto creo que ya te lo explicó @eferion en una conversación que tuviste con él, y en la que una de tus frases fué

> @eferion Tú podrías darme +50, ya que tu respuesta sólo quedó correcta basada en la mía (y tienes un montón) ;)

por lo poco que llevas en el sitio, parece que tienes muy buenos conocimientos y que puedes ser un usuario muy útil y reputado. Pero como me he permitido aconsejarte antes (espero que no te parezca mal), preocuparse mucho por la reputación no me parece una buena idea. Estoy seguro de que un usuario con tus conocimientos, alcanzará una reputación importante en poco tiempo. Pero la impaciencia no suele ser buena consejera. Espero que nos acompañes mucho tiempo en el sitio compartiendo con todos los usuarios :)

Comment: Detesto estar de acuerdo con vos :p

Comment: ¡Dijo todo! Menos de lo que se le preguntó. :(

Comment: Otro ejemplo de baja calidad, y muchos votos.

Comment: la conclusion es: no es bien visto pedir puntos, llamar a alguien que te de +1 a ti y no a los demas  si es asi no seriamos comunidad; para mi nada mas satisfactorio que otros usuarios que no conozco le guste mi respuesta

Comment: @jacknavarow ya lo compreendi

Comment: eres bienvenido en el [chat] alli puedes hablar con los grandes de las etiquetas aprender y entender mejor como funciona el sitio

Comment: @pikoh Sobre lo que dudas: [mire](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3997/los-votos-de-amigos-traen-baja-calidad-a-soes/4001#comment15450_4000) Como él dijo: *no es el mismo código*

Comment: @pikoh Me siento si mi mención te pareció irrespetuosa.
No lleve al lado personal, sólo cité porque su respuesta está basada principalmente en opiniones personales que se basó en mi historial, y en parte alguna agrega a resolver las cuestiones propuestas.
Una vez más te pido perdón. Gracias

Comment: @sbrubes disculpas aceptadas por supuesto. Olvidado por mi parte, y como te comento espero que sigas con tus aportaciones al sitio que pueden ser muy valiosas :)

Answer (score 4):

`los votos de amigos traen baja calidad a SOes`

¿ Tienes pruebas ? **NO, no las tienes**. Los votos **han sido, son, y serán** siempre anónimos. A partir de aquí, todo lo demás es pura especulación por tu parte. No hay mas que hablar ni mas que argumentar.

`no solo no compila como hace un grave acceso a memoria no válida (segmentation fault)`

`En otra, la que tiene más puntos no és la respuesta y la segunda no compila (y igual tenia un grave error de fuga de memoria)`

Al cabo del día, yo suelo visitar **muchas** preguntas / respuestas. Y de varios lenguajes. En algunos casos, me creo con los conocimientos necesarios para valorar tanto la pregunta como la respuesta. ¿ Tengo que comprobarlas **TODAS** ? ¿ Las preguntas y las respuestas ? **No**.

Normalmente, el error / fallo en la pregunta suele ser obvio. La explicación del error **es mas importante** que el código que acompaña a dicha explicación. Lo importante **NO es dar un pez**, sino **enseñar a pescar**.

¿ Puede que, en algún caso, otorgue puntos a respuestas **con gazapos** ? **SI**, es perfectamente posible. Si entiendo el problema, entiendo la respuesta, y estoy de acuerdo con ella, **voto positivo**. Si en el código se coló un pequeño error y me doy cuenta, **suelo dejar un comentario** (al igual que otros usuarios me avisan si soy yo el que cometió el error), y, en casos de usuarios nuevos con errores menores, yo mismo las edito y corrijo. **NO** las compruebo exhaustivamente todas.

Entiendo tu frustración. Cuando yo empecé aquí, tenía *ansias* de demostrar mis conocimientos. Respondía a todo lo que podía. Lógicamente, con respuestas mal elaboradas, no obtenía la puntuación que esperaba ... Con el tiempo, (creo) que escribo mejores respuestas. Y la comunidad me lo agradece con mejores puntuaciones. Puesdes comprobarlo en mi historial; incluso mi historial en Meta.

Como final, solo 4 consejos:

1. No des peces. Enseña a pescar. Explica el problema. Explica la solución.
2. Ten paciencia. El *efecto llamada* de usuarios con gran reputación **existe**. ¿ La única forma de contrarrestarlo ? Siendo tu un usuario de gran reputación. ¿ Como se consigue ? **Con el tiempo**.
3. La reputación **NO ES SOLO CALIDAD TÉCNICA**. También indica tu grado de implicación en la comunidad. Hay reputación por editar. Se otorgan *recompensas* en las preguntas destacadas. Implícate.
4. Participa. El efecto llamada se da en usuarios **conocidos**. Pregunta. Responde. Participa en Meta. Hazte ver.

**No** te tomes las cosas como algo personal. Lo único que sabemos de tí es lo que nos muestras con tu comportamiento. No sabemos tu nombre, ni tu edad, ni siquiera tu país. Ahora mismo, la impresión que yo tengo de ti es la de una persona con una tremenda *rabieta*. ¿ Eso es lo que quieres enseñarnos ? ¡ Esperamos ver tu mejor faceta !

Comment: Sólo quería ver si mis impresiones estaban equivocadas, y ahora me parece que están. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

> En [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247489/memoria-din%C3%A1mica-uso-de-realloc), la que tiene más puntos **no és la respuesta** y la segunda **no compila** (y igual tenia un grave error de *fuga de memoria*).

Buenas tardes [sbrubes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/120826/sbrubes). Revisa bien la respuesta que di porque sí que compila, tal y como puede verse en la [demo ejecutable](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0poU5KEZapRxd1qP) que anexé en los comentarios.

Respecto a las fugas de memoria, no eres la persona más adecuada para evaluar ese concepto, pues consideras que las fugas de memoria son aceptables, tal y como expones en los comentarios de [tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/247505/2742):

- Falta un `free` al finalizar `main`. [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247489/memoria-din%C3%A1mica-uso-de-realloc#comment459865_247505).
- No pasa nada.. No hay programa que quede con memoria sin executar. [sbrubes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247489/memoria-din%C3%A1mica-uso-de-realloc#comment459866_247505)
- Si pasa, como programadores tenemos la responsabilidad de hacernos cargo de los recursos del programa (es como si me dijeras que no pasa nada por tirar basura en la calle, ya pasará un barrendero a recogerla). La memoria no se *executa*, la memoria se usa. [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247489/memoria-din%C3%A1mica-uso-de-realloc#comment459868_247505).

Si pretendes sentar cátedra sobre fugas de memoria, deberías empezar por dar a la memoria el tratamiento que se merece, no el que te guste.

Mi última frase ha sonado muy agresiva, y esa agresividad es una decisión deliberada, si tienes dudas fundadas sobre mi conocimiento técnico te invito a visitar [todas mis respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster?tab=answers) y votar negativamente aquellas que consideres que no están a la altura.

Pediré explícitamente a los moderadores que no lo consideren un downvote masivo para que no tenga consecuencias sobre tu perfil, pero a cambio tendrás que argumentar debidamente tu motivación para el voto negativo, en otras palabras: deberás confrontar tu conocimiento al mío.

Comment: ¿Qué voto? ¿De qué estás hablando?

Comment: y aqui tienes un ejemplo @sbrubes , no le han marcado +1 siendo un usuario de 23k, no aplica tu concepto de amigos

Comment: @sbrubes Hablo de que "*te invito a visitar [todas mis respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster?tab=answers) y votar negativamente aquellas que consideres que no están a la altura*" y "*pero a cambio tendrás que argumentar debidamente tu motivación para el voto negativo*".

Comment: @paperbirdmaster No necesito probarte nada. Pero és mucho más grave un *dereferenced pointer* que un *free* al final del programa.
Además tú código allá está bien, lo que dehaste en SOes es que está mal, y es este que importa.

Comment: No des-referencio ningún puntero en el código, así que debemos estar hablando de cosas diferentes. Y no hay errores mejores y peores, todos los errores deben ser tenidos en consideración; el no liberar memoria es incorrecto y fomentar el no hacerlo no sólo contraproducente si no que es mala práctica. He revisado el código de la pregunta y el de Wandbox y tienes razón: no es el mismo código, lo corrijo, gracias.

Comment: @paperbirdmaster Pero lo hacías. No estoy interesado si eres mejor o peor que yo, apenas no le conozco. Y como lo dihe, tengo más lo que hacer que revisar sus errores.

Comment: @sbrubes No, ni en la versión anterior ni en la posterior des-referencio punteros (a no ser que contemos el indexado como des-referencia) así que debemos estar hablando de cosas distintas. Respecto a la batalla de conocimientos, la has empezado tú. Me parece muy bien que no quieras seguirla, tan bien como me parece que me señales en qué me equivoco para que pueda rectificar.